# Handling exception while calling external API using apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I need to call dowstream service **Service B**(given api contract) from my service, **Service A**, which is being called by the upstream systems.

Now I am using apache camel service instance for making a call to **Service B**, as given below :

**Request and Responses**:

```
public abstract class CamelRequest {
    private String route
}
public abstract class CamelResponse {
}
public class ServiceBRequest extends CamelRequest {
  // some fields are here
}
public class ServiceBResponse  extends CamelResponse {
   // some fields are here
}
```

**CamelService.java:**

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;

public abstract class CamelService {

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate template;
    
    protected abstract void preProcessor(CamelRequest req);
    protected abstract void postProcessor(CamelResponse res);

    public CamelResponse process(CamelRequest req, Map<String, Object> headers) throws CamelExecutionException {
    CamelResponse response = template.requestBodyAndHeaders(getRoute(req), req, headers, CamelResponse.class);
    log.debug(req.getRoute()+":: "+returnMetricsMessageHistoryService());
    return response;
    }

    private String getRoute(CamelRequest req) {
    return req.getRoute();
    }
}
```

**ServiceBImpl.java:**

```
public class ServiceBImpl extends CamelService {
    @Override
    public void preProcessor(CamelRequest req) {
    //Do nothing because no validation exist on downstream request object
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessor(CamelResponse res) {
    //Do nothing because no validation exist on downstream response object
    }
}
```

Call to downstream service **service B**:

```
public ServiceBResponse callServiceB(ServiceBRequest req, Map<String, Object> headers)
        throws CamelExecutionException{
    CamelService serviceBImpl = new ServiceBImpl();
    ServiceBResponse resp = (ServiceBResponse) serviceBImpl.process(req, headers);
    return resp;
}
```

Now when we call serviceB as:

```
template.requestBodyAndHeaders(getRoute(req), req, headers, CamelResponse.class);
```

this method throws **CamelExecutionException**.

> I need to figure out what possible exceptions can be wrapped inside this
> CamelExecutionException, so that I can handle them separately OR do different custom logging
> for different exceptions.

```
 For instance, for one exception:
 if(exception.getCause() instanceof java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException) 
 {//do something }
```

> What is the correct way to find out possible exceptions wrapped inside **CamelExecutionException** while calling an API ?

Comment: You cant.  There is no way for you to know in advance what exceptions a given API will throw at you, unless you have the code base and see it.

Your best bet is to look at the exception.getExchange().getException(), or exception.getCause() and see

Comment: @SusanMustafa, So how to create exceptional cases manually to see different kind exceptions inside CamelExecutionException?

Comment: Not sure if my answer is valid towards your question.  Otherwise clarify what exactly you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
     catch(CamelExecutionException camelException){

        Exception exchangeException = camelException.getExchange().getException();

        if (exchangeException != null && exchangeException.getCause() instanceof GoogleJsonResponseException) {

            GoogleJsonResponseException originalException = (GoogleJsonResponseException) exchangeException.getCause();

            return Response.status(originalException.getStatusCode()).build();
        }
        throw e;
    }
```

OR

```
catch(CamelExecutionException camelException){

        final Throwable cause = camelException.getCause();

        if (cause instanceof HttpOperationFailedException) {
            final HttpOperationFailedException httpError = (HttpOperationFailedException) cause;
        }

        throw camelError;

    }
```

Comment: Yeah that I understood but what changes should I make in Req or URL or any other thing, to produce generate these exception via calling the services

Comment: I dont understand your question.   Lets answer the following questions first:

1- Are you getting exceptions now?
2- If yes, What is the exception Type?, Its cause()?
3- If no, What is it that you want to happen()?
4- Are you using SOAP or REST?
5- Have you looked into onException() from Camel?https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html

Comment: I am doing REST http Dowstream call from my API, I am not getting exceptions right now, But I want to generate exception and figure out what could possible general exceptions might arise while calling REST endpoint using apache camel, so that in future if they arise than I'll able to customize the logging for them, as per Buisness requirement

Comment: @tusharRawat Generally if you are calling another API (and in this case, it is a REST Call), you are going to depend on the HTTP Status codes that the service you are calling generates.  You can NOT find out what all possible exceptions that second API is going to be throwing at you.  Your best to handle what you know can occur + log